# How to run a RANK() function on a model

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

How can I run a [rank function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to generate an attribute on a given sequelize model?

For example, given the model:

```js
Players.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    rating: type: DataTypes.FLOAT
  },
  { sequelize }
)
```

I would like to get an attribute `rank` when running `Players.getAll({ rank: rating })`. This would generate SQL similar to:

```
SELECT id, rating, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rating DESC) as rank FROM players
```

How would I do this using sequelize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Sequelize Literal Function like follows -

```
attributes: [
          'id', 'rating',
          [Sequelize.literal('(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rating DESC))'), 'rank']
    ]
```

to create new attributes.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but I'm having another problem: this `rank` attribute is only available on the returned query if I `JSON.stringify()` it. This is a problem because stringifying the returned model omits properties via getters, which I also have. I found a workaround where I combine the stringified model with the original model, but this seems hacky. Any idea how to access these attributes directly on the model without stringifying?

Comment: I figured out that `Model.get()` will return attributes added this way, but it will only return virtual getters if they are defined as attributes in `Model.init()` and not in the Model's class definition.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, +1 for you .